# How to handle errors in Sinatra from external file?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, helper

I'm trying to handle errors in a Sinatra App including a Helper Module. I tried doing it like this:

```
# application_controller.rb
require './application_helper'

class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
    helpers Sinatra::ApplicationHelper

end
```

```
# application_helper.rb

require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module ApplicationHelper
    error StandardError do |e|
      handle_error 500, e
    end
  end

  helpers ApplicationHelper
end
```

But I cannot make it work, it is raising the error:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `error' for Sinatra::ApplicationHelper:Module
```

How can I use `error` in an external module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `helpers` method, you need to [define a `registered method`](http://sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#setting-options-and-other-extension-setup) on your helper module. In this method the parameter passed is your app, and you can use it to configure errors, for example:

```ruby
module Sinatra
  module ApplicationHelper

    def self.registered(app)
      app.error StandardError do |e|
        handle_error 500, e
      end
    end
  end

  register ApplicationHelper
end
```

Then in your app file you use `register` instead of `helpers`:

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::ApplicationHelper

end
```

You might want to add some helpers at the same time you register your extension, for example in this case you might want to include the `handle_error` method in the extension. To do that you can add another helper module inside your extension module, and call `app.helpers` to include it in `registered`.

```
module Sinatra
  module ApplicationHelper

    module Helpers
      def handle_error(code, error)
        #... Helper code here.
      end

      # Other helpers if needed.
    end

    def self.registered(app)
      app.error StandardError do |e|
        handle_error 500, e
      end

      # Include helpers at registration.
      app.helpers Helpers
    end
  end

  register ApplicationHelper
end
```